# How do I give Wheatley a custom skin in Portal 2?

Tags: mods, portal-2

I really love to edit my skins in games, but Portal 2 is using .vpk package files where it takes the skins from so I can not easily just put the .vtf files into the Portal 2 map.

How do I give Wheatley a custom skin in Portal 2?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[VPK stands for **Valve Pak**](http://developer.valvesoftware.com/wiki/VPK), these are files that are uncompressed archives used to package content (never code). They are the successors to GCFs, and when passed to the `addoninstaller` tool are also used to distribute add-ons like custom campaigns.

VPKs can be created with the command line tool `vpk`, found at `<game>\bin\`. This has been introduced in the Left 4 Dead branch and Alien Swarm branch games and has been adopted into the Portal branch.

You can get your custom skins working by creating a custom folder that adapts the VPK structure and then you can drag that custom folder on the `vpk` tool so it creates a `.vpk` file for you. Then, you drag that `.vpk` file onto the `addoninstaller`.

Have fun! :)

PS: You can use GCFScape to view the `.vpk` files.

---

**Extra remarks**:

> Since the SDK is not released yet, there's no official vpk.exe available for Portal 2. I wouldn't change that sentence for now, even though you could also use the vpk.exe from the other SDKs.
>
> — Barracuda 21:09, 20 April 2011 (UTC)